# Which is the best tool for free temporary email service?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, qa-developer

I checked the various tools for it but want to know about the best tool for my requirement.

found some of the high rated tools on web:

1. [TEMPMAIL](https://temp-mail.org/en/)
2. [MAILDROP](https://maildrop.cc/)
3. [MAILINATOR](https://www.mailinator.com/)
4. [Mail7](https://www.mail7.io/)
5. [YOPMAIL](http://www.yopmail.com/en/)

Although I tried all listed services.

I want to implement the temporary emails in manual testing, automation as well. I've used Mailinator but it's not free after some time. So I'm looking for something else, my requirements are:

- it's free
- it creates emails only temporarily
- it provides an API

What would you recommend?

Comment: What exactly do you expect? That it's free and temporary, or do you have other requirements?

Comment: @pavelsaman I raise this question because I want to know the best tool for disposable email service. which is free to use.

Comment: But best is hard to define unless you know what you want. And you don't really have requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Both Mailinator & Mail7 are good email services, but I personally like Mail7 more. There are various reasons behind my choice.

First of all, it is completely free as of now and its free Pro Plan allows me to create 25 Private Inboxes with Unlimited Emails / Day. And there is Up to 3 days Email Retention. It also gives me 25MB Storage.

I have also found Mail7's documentation more intuitive as compare to other services. There are many more documents there on Mail7, in which it is explained about how to use this temporary service while automating your testing efforts.

Apart from these, there are few more benefits of using Mail7 as compare to using other email services.

So you can give it a try and see if it fits into your requirement.

Comment: As a software testing company we recommend to use Microsoft Office Outlook as it is paid and has a good integration if needed. Else you can also use Mozilla Thunderbird or Gmail client in case you need to test automated or manual emails.